# Reset passwords on Business Objects Enterprise XI

Tags: password, reset, businessobjects

I have been given a legacy Business Objects Enterprise XI Server and nobody knows the passwords for it.

How do I reset the authentication database table/config file/whatever so that I can log into the web front-end again?

Currently I am prompted a web page named "Log on to InfoView" with a "Log On to BusinessObjects"/"Existing User" login form.

The exact setup is

- Business Objects Enterprise XI (Developer License, AFAIK)
- Windows Server 2003
- SQL Server 2000 DB Backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to reset the authentication is to re-create the Business Objects database by bring up the CCM and stopping the CMS.  Go to the configuration tab and click on the specify button.  Ask for it Re-create/Re-initialize the database.  Start the CMS up again.

Once this is done, there will be only 2 users, Administrator and Guest.  Both with no passwords.